# ORACLE 10g group by into columns

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle10g

I've got the following query

```
select mem.irsc_zona,
(case 
  when mem.irsc_membres = 1
    then mem.irsc_valor
end) "1 membre",
(case 
  when mem.irsc_membres = 2
    then mem.irsc_valor
end) "2 membres",
(case 
  when mem.irsc_membres = 3
    then mem.irsc_valor
end) "3 membres",
(case 
  when mem.irsc_membres = 4
    then mem.irsc_valor
end) "4 membres"
from 
(select aip.irsc_zona, aip.irsc_membres, aip.irsc_valor from
ajt_irsc_peu aip
where aip.IRSC_FACTOR = '2.35'
and aip.IRSC_DATA_FI = TO_DATE('31/12/15')) mem;
```

returning the following

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| IRSC_ZONA | 1 membre | 2 membres | 3 membres | 4 membres |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| A         | 2080,46  |           |           |           |
| A         |          | 2144,81   |           |           |
| A         |          |           | 2237,06   |           |
| A         |          |           |           | 2311,62   |
| B         | 1950,43  |           |           |           |
| B         |          | 2010,76   |           |           |
| B         |          |           | 2097,24   |           |
| B         |          |           |           | 2167,14   |
| C         | 1835,7   |           |           |           |
| C         |          | 1892,48   |           |           |
| C         |          |           | 1973,87   |           |
| C         |          |           |           | 2039,66   |
| D         | 1560,35  |           |           |           |
| D         |          | 1608,61   |           |           |
| D         |          |           | 1677,79   |           |
| D         |          |           |           | 1733,72   |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| IRSC_ZONA | 1 membre | 2 membres | 3 membres | 4 membres |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| A         | 2080,46  | 2144,81   | 2237,06   | 2311,62   |
| B         | 1950,43  | 2010,76   | 2097,24   | 2167,14   |
| C         | 1835,7   | 1892,48   | 1973,87   | 2039,66   |
| D         | 1560,35  | 1608,61   | 1677,79   | 1733,72   |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

So, I would like to have the results grouped by IRSC_ZONA, problem is I am getting:

```
ORA-00979: no es una expresión GROUP BY
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 4, columna: 8
```

I don't know how to restructure my query to get the expected result.

Hope my question is clear.
 If not, please tell me how I could give more details.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add in the aggregate function around your case statements.

Something like the following should do the trick (obviously, you'd use your actual query in place of where I use "sample_data"):

```
with sample_data as (select 'A' irsc_zona, 2080.46 irsc_valor, 1 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'A' irsc_zona, 2144.81 irsc_valor, 2 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'A' irsc_zona, 2237.06 irsc_valor, 3 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'A' irsc_zona, 2311.62 irsc_valor, 4 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'B' irsc_zona, 1950.43 irsc_valor, 1 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'B' irsc_zona, 2010.76 irsc_valor, 2 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'B' irsc_zona, 2097.24 irsc_valor, 3 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'B' irsc_zona, 2167.14 irsc_valor, 4 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'C' irsc_zona, 1835.7 irsc_valor, 1 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'C' irsc_zona, 1892.48 irsc_valor, 2 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'C' irsc_zona, 1973.87 irsc_valor, 3 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'C' irsc_zona, 2039.66 irsc_valor, 4 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'D' irsc_zona, 1560.35 irsc_valor, 1 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'D' irsc_zona, 1608.61 irsc_valor, 2 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'D' irsc_zona, 1677.79 irsc_valor, 3 irsc_membres from dual union all
                     select 'D' irsc_zona, 1733.72 irsc_valor, 4 irsc_membres from dual)
select irsc_zona,
       sum(decode(irsc_membres, 1, irsc_valor)) "1 membre",
       sum(decode(irsc_membres, 2, irsc_valor)) "2 membre",
       sum(decode(irsc_membres, 3, irsc_valor)) "3 membre",
       sum(decode(irsc_membres, 4, irsc_valor)) "4 membre"
from   sample_data
group by irsc_zona
order by irsc_zona;

IRSC_ZONA   1 membre   2 membre   3 membre   4 membre
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A            2080.46    2144.81    2237.06    2311.62
B            1950.43    2010.76    2097.24    2167.14
C             1835.7    1892.48    1973.87    2039.66
D            1560.35    1608.61    1677.79    1733.72
```

N.B. you'll note that I switched to using decode statements, which I've done mainly because it makes the query a bit more readable, as it takes up less space. I also used SUM as the aggregate function, just in case you could have multiple rows per zona and membres.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed! As soon as i get my reputation up, I'll mark this as the correct answer. Unfortunately, can't to that yet.

Comment: Marked it as correct! Was trying to upvote instead of checking it as correct answer. Once again, thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome! You were mostly there, anyway - you were just missing the sum()/max() to aggregate the data *{:-)